# Reaching inherited classes with only base class property in JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

Let's say I have a structure like below: A MappedSuperclass, then a general main class and subclasses extended from this main class. And these subclasses have some other children classes too...

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Auto)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Version
    @Column (name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
    protected Long version

    // **** Setters getters etc...
}


@Entity 
@Table (name = "PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PERSON_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.String, length = 50)
@DiscriminatorValue("PERSONBASE")
public class PersonEO extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SURNAME")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "PHONENO")
    private Long phoneNo;

    // **** Other properties / constructors & setters-getters...
}

@Entity 
@Table(name = "ENGINEER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) 
@DiscriminatorValue("ENGINEER")
public class EngineerEO extends PersonEO{

    @Column(name = "UNIVERSITY", length = 50)
    private String university;

    @Column(name = "GPA")
    private double gpa;

    // **** Other properties / constructors & setters-getters...
}

@Entity 
@Table(name = "CLERK")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) 
@DiscriminatorValue("CLERK")
public class ClerkEO extends PersonEO{

    @Column(name = "PLACE_OF_WORK", length = 50)
    private String pow;

    @Column(name = "EXPERTISE", length = 50)
    private String expertise;

    // **** Other properties / constructors & setters-getters...
}
```

I have read that using *"DiscriminatorValue"* in runtime with something like

```
@Transient
public String getDecriminatorValue() {
    return this.getClass().getAnnotation(DiscriminatorValue.class).value();
}
```

is not a *"correct"* approach... So my question is; if somebody have the *"id"* from *BaseEntity* or lets say *"PhoneNo"* from *PersonEO*, how can he query information from a specific table like *Clerk* or *Engineer* (or may be lower class) without knowing any other information(type of the class)?

I mean I know nothing but the "ID" and I want to get all the properties from the table which the data belongs to. But I have no idea if it is an Engineer or Clerk etc...

What is the most efficient way to make this kind of relation?

Thanks indeed...

Comment: em.find(BaseClass, id) will get the object and return the correct type (using discriminator info, or whatever internally).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, what if instead of Id we have only lets say "PhoneNo", how can we reach, for instance, "Clerk"  without knowing the Type?

Comment: If you have PhoneNo then you KNOW it is a PersonEO (or subclass). So do a JPQL "SELECT p FROM PersonEO p WHERE phoneNumber = :ph". This returns the objects in the right type

Comment: So in this case "SELECT p FROM PersonEO p WHERE phoneNumber = :ph" will return a ClerkEO? I thought that query will return "only" the record in Person table not the additional properties in CLERK table.

Comment: If some "phoneNo" corresponds to an object of type ClerkEO then it returns a ClerkEO ... that is one of the reasons for using an ORM. Which fields are returned depends on the JPA implementation. Others can be lazy loaded as necessary.